# Shared Preference is freezing my app - Android mobile app

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

So I'm trying to create a shared preference and the app was working fine then all of a sudden it broke.

I have knuckled it down to the exact line that is breaking the code and I'm not sure exactly how to fix it.

Any suggestions?

Here's my current code:

```
    public class studentEmail extends Activity {
    private WebView mWebview;

    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.student_email) ;



final SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

mWebview = new WebView(this);


        final EditText emEdit   = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editEmail);
        final EditText passEdit   = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editPass);

if(preferences.getString("username", null).isEmpty() && preferences.getString("password", null).isEmpty())
    {

        mWebview  = new WebView(this);

        mWebview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); // enable javascript

        final Activity activity = this;

        mWebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                Toast.makeText(activity, description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Preference is empty :)", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        TextView text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        TextView textEmail = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewEmail);
        TextView textPass = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewPass);
        TextView textTitle = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewTitle);
        text.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC);
        textEmail.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC);
        textPass.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC);
        textTitle.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC);
        text.setTextSize(android.util.TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX,26);
        textEmail.setTextSize(android.util.TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX,26);
        textPass.setTextSize(android.util.TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX,26);
        textTitle.setTextSize(android.util.TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, 40);
        textTitle.setText("E-mail Login");
        text.setText("\n\nPlease enter your Student E-mail and Password.\n");
        textEmail.setText("E-Mail:");
        textPass.setText("\nPassword:");

        final EditText emailValidate = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editEmail);
        final TextView emailValMsg = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.emailValidate);
        final EditText password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editPass);

emailValidate.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                String email = emailValidate.getText().toString().trim();
                String emailPattern = "[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@mail+\\.+itsligo+\\.+ie+";

                if (email.matches(emailPattern) && s.length() > 0)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your e-mail is now valid! :)", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    // or
                    emailValMsg.setText("Valid email");
                }
                else
                {
                    emailValMsg.setText("Invalid email !");
                }
            }
        });

final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loginButton);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String email = emailValidate.getText().toString().trim();
                String emailPattern = "[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-z]+\\.+[a-z]+";

                if (emailValidate.getText().toString().trim().matches("") || password.getText().toString().trim().matches("")) {
                    if (emailValidate.getText().toString().trim().matches("") && password.getText().toString().trim().matches("")) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter an E-mail Address and Password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else if (emailValidate.getText().toString().trim().matches("")) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter an E-mail Address", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else if (password.getText().toString().trim().matches("")) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter a Password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }

else {
                    mWebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                        @Override
                        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                            String webUrl = mWebview.getUrl();

                                    CheckBox cbox1 = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkbox_store);

                            if (cbox1.isChecked())
                            {

                            }
                            mWebview.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " + "document.getElementById('cred_userid_inputtext').value ='" + emEdit.getText() + "';" + "})()");
                            mWebview.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " + "document.getElementById('cred_password_inputtext').value ='" + passEdit.getText() + "';" + "})()");
                            mWebview.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " + "document.getElementById('credentials').submit(); return false;" + "})()");
                        }
                    });

                    mWebview.loadUrl("http://login.microsoftonline.com");
                    setContentView(mWebview);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "This works!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }

            }
        });
    }

else
    {

        mWebview  = new WebView(this);

        mWebview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); // enable javascript

        final Activity activity = this;

        mWebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                Toast.makeText(activity, description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        mWebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                String webUrl = mWebview.getUrl();

                mWebview.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " + "document.getElementById('cred_userid_inputtext').value ='" + preferences.getString("username", null).toString() + "';" + "})()");
                mWebview.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " + "document.getElementById('cred_password_inputtext').value ='" + preferences.getString("password", null).toString() + "';" + "})()");
                mWebview.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " + "document.getElementById('credentials').submit(); return false;" + "})()");
            }
        });

mWebview.loadUrl("http://login.microsoftonline.com");
        setContentView(mWebview);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Preferences have something", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
}
}
```

Errors:

```
02-14 19:20:06.130      632-632/com.example.PorjectStudent E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.PorjectStudent/com.example.PorjectStudent.studentEmail}: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

02-14 19:20:06.130      632-632/com.example.PorjectStudent E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    at com.example.PorjectStudent.studentEmail.onCreate(studentEmail.java:35)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
                at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-14 19:42:37.971      677-677/com.example.PorjectStudent E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.PorjectStudent/com.example.PorjectStudent.studentEmail}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.example.PorjectStudent.studentEmail.onCreate(studentEmail.java:39)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
                at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I really am stumped and the solution is probably simple but it's been wrecking my brain all day so I decided to ask for help as I haven't progressed in hours!

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: Can you add the exception stack trace to your question?

Comment: Is that your **full** stacktracke? It's necessary to add it complete as it might have details not shown right now.

Comment: That's the full thing as of now! There's nothing more showing up!

Comment: Which line is the 35th of your studentEmail.java file?

Comment: final EditText emEdit   = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editEmail);

That's the 35th line

Comment: I don't know whether the log you've posted corresponds to your current code, but if you're getting an exception there, usually is related to your initial issue. Try cleaning up your project, recompile and run again.

Answer (score 2):

You have to call `setContentView(R.layout.student_email);` immediately after `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);`. You're placing your `SharedPreferences` in the middle and you can't do that.

As a generic rule, these two sentences have to be the first ones on any `onCreate()` method (at least within an `Activity`).

**---- EDIT ----**

```
public class studentEmail extends Activity {
private WebView mWebview;

public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.student_email) ;

    final SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE); //This line breaks the code

    mWebview = new WebView(this);

    final EditText emEdit   = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editEmail);
    final EditText passEdit   = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editPass);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I didn't know this.

However, the same issue is still occurring. I'll post my full code above incase there is any other issues I'm not seeing.

Comment: Just click on edit in your own question and add the code you need. Don't forget to provide the stacktrace also, it's very important.

Comment: You still have the code as you shouldn't! Have a look at the code I've updated within my answer, that's how it has to be.

Comment: Apologies! I actually had changed it in my code! But added the rest of my code to the one I posted here.

I have the setContentview immediately after the create and the sharedpreference after as above now but it still crashes!

Answer (score 0):

You must always start your custom codes AFTER `setContentView(R.layout...) ;`.